# Check if element is in a jquery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I initialize a jQuery collection like so

```
$collection = $([])
```

later on some things happend and I do a lot of

```
$collection = $collection.add($element)
```

I do this so that I can call functions like `$collection.hide()` on all of the elements at once.

The problem is that later I want to do something like `_.contains($collection, $element)` but this doesn't work.
For example:

```
var $b = $("#content")
var $c = $([]).add(b)
console.log( _.contains($c, $b) )
console.log( _.contains($c.toArray(), $b)
```

Both evaluate to false.

How can I accomplish my goal with jQuery?

Comment: jQuery objects act-like Array, so the issue with _.contains is the same in both cases. Even `$b` is a *sequence/set of elements* (0 or 1 in this case). The following should do the trick: `_.contains($c, $b[0])`, but is not the most appropriate method for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if ($c.is($b)) // $c contains $b
```

Note that `.is` goes out of its way to make life easy: you can pass a selector (e.g. `"#content"`), or an element (e.g. `document.getElementById("content")`), or a jQuery object (e.g. `$("#content")`) and it will work as expected in each case.

Comment: oh wow thanks haha. I was just checking the API never noticed .is. Thanks! :D

Comment: @Nonconformist: To tell the truth it's not very discoverable on its own. But you can zero in on it by going to browse the [filtering](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/) category, which does sound like a promising lead.